# If is a checkbox Checked do

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

i have an issue.

I'm trying avoid the user leaves the page if theres any element checked.

For instance, i have several checkboxes with a class named "testCheckbox" and i tried that:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
if($('.testCheckbox').attr('checked'))
    return  'yes';
else
    return 'no';}}
```

But it always is says 'yes' when the first checkbox (in order of appear) is checked, if i check the second or the third, etc, says 'no'.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [checked-selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) along with with [is](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

```
if ($('.testCheckbox').is(':checked'))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($('.testCheckbox:checked').length)
```

Answer (score -2):

your probably wanting to do something like this

```
    window.onbeforeunload = function()
    {
        var yesno = 'no';
        $('.testCheckbox').each(function(index,value){
            if($(value).attr('checked'))
            {
                yesno = 'yes';
                return  false;
            }
        });
        return yesno;
    }
```